# PHPSESSID Changing and thus invalidating the session

Tags: session-cookies, php

I'm getting a problem with my current system,

In my database, I've a table, mapuser which contains two fields, PHPSESSID and UserId. I'm preferring to persisting my session in the database. The problem I'm getting is that everytime I'm completly closing my browser and opening it again, I'm getting a new PHPSESSID and thus invalidating my previous session.

I'm getting this error will all browser I'm using

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist the session id, you could store it in a cookie (encrypted!). That way, you can compare it with the one stored in the db.

Comment: ya, this is OK, but the PHPSESSID itself is changing

Comment: When you open your browser after you've closed it, you could read the session id from the cookie and set it using `session_id()`. Then you would have the same session id as before.

Comment: yes, but when the browser is closing, I'm loosing all my cookies, by the way, is this normal??

Comment: That is dependent on your browser settings and the expiry time of the cookie you set.